# What test should I perform on a log-normal, continuous variable?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, data-transformation

I have continuous, log-normal dependent variable(# pens in hospital). I want to know if a dichotomous variable (using a specific EMR or not) results in a significant decrease in this variable.

Would it best to log-transform the variable and do a paired t-test on the log-transformed variable? Are there more appropriate tests I should consider? Would a multiple linear regression work better so I can control for other variables (e.g., # of employees)?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: 1. Number of pens is NOT continuous, it's discrete, and certainly not lognormal. It may perhaps be reasonable to treat it as if it were continuous or even lognormal, but that doesn't make it the case. 2. What matters is its conditional distribution, not the marginal distribution; you're not in a position to actually assess that ... ctd

Comment: ctd...  from the data you're trying to test without impacting the properties of your test, unless you take some data out for model selection 3. "EMR" will be unknown to many of our readers; expand the abbreviation or describe it (I presume you mean to introduce an electronic medical record system, which would presumably reduce the need for pens; if so make that clearer in the question). 4. Roughly how many hospitals are there? 5. If you have other variables that would be likely to impact the response, you should make that clear at the start, rather than mentioning it *after* you suggest a test